# Making an Ajax call within a loaded element without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have an index page, which we'll call index.php that has JavaScript code to load some page within a div that looks something like this

```
 /*load site s into div */
    function load(s) {
       var ele = document.getElementById('injecthere');
       xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

       xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) { 
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         ele.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
       }

 xhr.open("GET", s, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
 xhr.send();
}
```

So the problem goes something like this: index.php -> load function injects PHP file (lets call it form.php) -> code from form.php performs an ajax form submission -> page return to index.php before ajax is completed, so no data gets sent. I have tried everything from preventDefault() to return false.

The Ajax form request works as expected when I get to form.php via a link, but it does not work when I come to form.php via the load function.

**Update:** The script for form.php appears to not load when injected via the load function. Is there a way to get the scripts for form.php to be loaded?

Comment: Where is the variable `site` coming from in your `xhr.open` call? Should that just be `s`?

Comment: Sorry that was suppose to be s, it has been updated.

Comment: OK. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: No, I still have the same issue.

Comment: An Ajax call will not open or display another HTML page by magic. You simply cannot expect the Ajax target to interact with the user in any way. If you want to have the user fill a form, just open a popup or redirect your current page, but Ajax will not do that trick.